# Joint Data from Has Many Through Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using has many through relationship in my Rails4 application because many of the answers from stackoverflow users suggested it more than HABTM. Unfortunately I couldn't figure it out how to call relational data from my join model's (called "participation") view pages. I have 3 issues:

**1.In app/views/participations/show.html.erb**

I would like to make a call like this to return prefered exam_center's city field which kept under the exam_centers table:

```
<%= @participation.exam_center_preference %>
```

But it's only returning the ID. I need to fetch the exam_center's "city" field with this ID number.

**2.In app/views/participations/index.html.erb**

I need to make exactly the same thing in show.html.erb

```
<%= participation.examination.bookings %>
```

**3. In app/views/participations/_form_html.erb**

I don't know how to call data from exam_centers model in my **form partial** for Participation model. When I use something like this;

```
<%= f.input :exam_center_preference, collection:Booking.where(examination_id: @examination.id), label: 'Choose', label_method: :id %>
```

It's returning ID's of related exam_centers - but I also need "city" values from ExamCenter model as label_method.

See collection and label_method below:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@examination, @participation]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :exam_center_preference, collection:HOW?, label: 'Choose', label_method: HOW? %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Save", :class => 'btn btn-large btn-warning' %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the my model structure:

**examination.rb:**

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

  has_many :bookings
  has_many :exam_centers, :through => :bookings
end
```

**participation.rb:**

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examination
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  foo-bar
end
```

As you can see I'm having "Participation" as a join model between Examination and User models.

I also have this kind of relationship between Examination and ExamCenter with a "Booking" join model. This is the structure =>

**examination.rb**

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  you-can-see-above
end
```

**booking.rb**

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :examination
  belongs_to :exam_center
end
```

**exam_center.rb**

```
class ExamCenter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :examinations, :through => :bookings
end
```

**Schema Structure => **

```
  create_table "examinations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "shortname"
    t.datetime "exam_date"
  end

  create_table "participations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "examination_id"
    t.boolean  "payment_status"
    t.string   "language_preference"
    t.string   "exam_center_preference"
  end

  create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "examination_id"
    t.integer  "exam_center_id"
  end

  create_table "exam_centers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "building"
    t.text     "address"
  end
```

**Routes =>**

```
resources :exam_statuses, :exam_centers, :exam_fees
resources :examinations do
  resources :participations do
    member do
      get :update_profile_information
      get :approve_application
    end
  end
end
```